# Counting objects in image

Tags: count, opencv, computer-vision

I want to count no of objects in an image using open cv. I have a soybean image and now I want to count the soybean numbers. If possible please help me and let me know the counting algorithms.

Thanks and I look forward to hear from you.

Regards,
Sumon

Comment: you should check this other post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378579/opencv-grouping-white-pixels

Answer (score 6):

Sumon,
  There is no one algorithm for counting objects.  It greatly depends on the image itself.  Depending on the contrast of the beans to the background it may be possible to use a simple threshold then a labeling algorithm, or even just finding contours.

The threshold function in opencv is cvThreshold.  The contour finding algorithm is cvFindContours using this you could count the number of contours found.

Also the blob library has many facilities for this type of machine vision applications including connected component labeling which is basically what you need here.  The library's description I believe is already included in opencv. The description of it can be found [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib).

I could provide some more assistance if I knew a little more about the image.